# Textbook on Approximation

Tags: reference-request, approximation, book-recommendation

Does anyone know of a good book on approximations methods?  In particular finding approximations to sums, integrals, etc via upper/ lower bounds, power series approximations, etc and bounding the error of the approximation.

This topic has always been a weak point for me.  When I'm in some QM or analysis class or something and a professor says "and then of course this is approximately '...'" I usually don't see how they got there without at least a few minutes of effort.  Sometimes I still can't figure it out.  And it's even harder to find approximations for myself than to just verify that a given approximation works.

Is there some textbook that goes over stuff like this?  Whenever I google it I get stuff for computer science algorithms.

Comment: The approximation $x=0$ is typically off by at most a finite amount.

Comment: It sounds like the key phrase for what you're looking for in texts would be "asymptotic analysis".